# Access chrome sandbox file system

Tags: google-chrome-app

Is there any way to save files to chrome app sandopx file system using chrome.filesystem? How do i get chrome sand box file system access using chrome.filesystem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome apps access the sandbox file system the same way as normal web pages can, so y ou don't need to use chrome.fileSystem at all. chrome.fileSystem is just for accessing files outside of the sandbox.

See http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/ for info on getting started with sandboxed file systems. The one Chrome App specific thing you'll need to do is add the unlimitedStorage permission to your app.

Comment: 'chrome.fileSystem is just for accessing files outside of the sandbox', Nope, fileSystem creates a virtual directory for handling user files, this means you are not accessing directly to hardrive fileSystem, only is creating a safe space where you can read, write and work with directories inside this sandbox, but the original route of a file is always protected and is always different as the sandbox storage, so, no you are not acessing to the files outside the sandbox, you are accessing to a direct reference of the original file route like URL.createObjectURL method.